# Does Ubuntu support the OpenBSD Crypto Framework?

Tags: server, security, encryption

I can't seem to find an answer to this question. There is the Linux Crypto API, and the OpenBSD Crypto Framework (OCF). I can't find anyting on Google as to whether Ubuntu supports OCF or if the Ubuntu kernel uses the Linux Crypto API.

I'm particularly interested in Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS Server if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu definitely uses the Linux Crypto API (which is available for kernels from 2.6.4)

I think for OCF, you need to use the **[OCF-Linux port](http://ocf-linux.sourceforge.net/)**